# Single word meaning "Treasure Hunter"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a single word which means something close to "treasure hunter". However, "treasure hunter" may not mean exactly what I want. I want a word that describes a person whose job is to search for rare items:

"What does he do?"

"He is a *treasure hunter*, he searches for rare or valuable items."

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-another-word-for-treasure-hunter